# Remix IDE doesn't download all files from imports

Tags: solidity, remix

I have a problem in remix ide: when I import a file from github it automatically download it in .deps, but when that file imports other files from an outside directory (like import "../../etc) remix doesn't download those files and it gives errors

Comment: Can you share a minimal example where the problem shows? I'd guess that remix is failing to understand the import path.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and for some reason it ended up being that I was using the wrong compiler version. Not sure if this will fix your issue, but try checking that.